# How to replace lines in notepad++ that has a variable value?

Tags: notepad++

I want to all change lines that have the following :

```
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0049999999
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0069999999
```

And some other values that can be different so that they all are :

```
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0
```

I've searched and read some previous posts but when I switch to regular expression it can't find any of the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to escape `[` and `]` by using `\[` and `\]`?

- Find = `GameData\["cost_ext"\]\["upkeep"\]\["manpower"\]\h*=\h*\K[\d\.]+`
- Replace = `0`
- Search Mode = regular expression

source data:

```
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0049999999 
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0069999999
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0059999999
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0039999999
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0019999999
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0.0079999999
```

final data:

```
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0 
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0
GameData["cost_ext"]["upkeep"]["manpower"] = 0
```

Comment: That worked. I didn't use `\[` and `\]`. Thank you very very much for the help.